How long will it take for Polya's Urn to have the same Ratio as it had in the Beginning?
Recently I learned that in Polya's Urn starting with $m$ red balls and $n$ blue balls ... as time goes to infinity, the ratio of red to blue balls converges to its initial ratio (Polya's urn model - limit distribution). Intuitively, I interpret this as follows:

At $t=0$, the ratio of red to blue balls is $\frac{m}{n}$
At $t=\infty$, the ratio of red to blue balls is also $\frac{m}{n}$

This brings me to my question:
Define $t$ as the time  between $(0, \infty)$, at which the ratio of red to blue balls is again $\frac{m}{n}$:
$$ \min \{ t > 0 \colon \frac{R(t)}{B(t)} = \frac{m}{n} \} $$
What is the probability distribution of $t$, $P(T=t)$ ? In other words, how long will it take for Polya's Urn to first return to the same ratio of balls as it had in the beginning?
I thought that perhaps this could be modelled as a asymmetrical Random Walk, and thus we could treat this problem as a Hitting Time Distribution question (e.g. First Hitting Time Distribution of a Random Walk with Drift follows an Inverse Gaussian Distribution), but I was not sure how to set this up.
Instead, I tried to find out the Expected Value and Variance of $t$.
1) Expected Value: Start with
$$m = \text{initial number of red balls}$$
$$n = \text{initial number of blue balls}$$
The total number of balls at the start is:
$$N = m + n$$
In Polya's Urn model, the ratio of red to blue balls at t = ∞ converges to the initial ratio:
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{R(t)}{B(t)} = \frac{m}{n}$$
where $R(t)$ and $B(t)$ are the numbers of red and blue balls at time $t$.
To find when we expect the ratio to be $m:n$ again, we need to consider the expected number of balls added before this occurs. Let's call this as x.
We can define a logical relationship as:
$$\frac{m+x\frac{m}{m+n}}{n+x\frac{n}{m+n}} = \frac{m}{n}$$
Solving this equation:
$$\frac{m(m+n)+xm}{n(m+n)+xn} = \frac{m}{n}$$
$$m(m+n)+xm = m(m+n)+xm$$
$$E(T) = x = m+n = N$$
Thus, it seems as if once you after $N$ turns have passed such that $N$ equals the original number of balls - the ratio of red to blue balls after $N$ turns will also be the same as the ratio of red to blue balls at the start.
2) Variance I am unsure how to calculate the Variance . I started doing this:
$$P(\text{red at t}) = \frac{X_t}{X_t + Y_t}$$
$$E(T^2) = \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} t^2 \cdot P(T=t)$$
But I am not sure how to continue.
Can someone please show me how to derive the variance for the time in this problem? And is it possible to get a PDF (rather PMF) for the time?
Notes:

https://observablehq.com/@cmoog/polya-urn-simulation

Edit: Some Visualizations of an Urn that starts with a ratio of 3:5 and how it returns to its original ratio (I can include the R code if anyone is interested):




I don't think the premise of the question is correct: the proportion as $t\to\infty$ isn't going to converge to the initial proportion. (Imagine we start with one ball of each colour; then this would say the proportion would converge to $\frac12$. But after the first draw, there are two balls of one colour and one of the other, so the proportion would have to converge to $\frac23$ or $\frac13$ also...?) The linked file seems to say that when we start with one ball of each colour, the limiting ratio is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

@Greg martin: thank you for the feedback. I will make the changes in the morning. I was just curious to know when will the urn first have the same ratio as its initial ratio. Thank you so much!

Do you know for sure if $\min { t > 0 \colon \frac{R(t)}{B(t)} = \frac{m}{n} }$ is finite with probability $1$?

@ Varun: thank you for your reply! I will think about this...

@GregMartin It seems to me that this is a matter of confusing a random variable with its expectation. The expected proportion at the end is 1/2, as the process after one step devolves into a process with expectation either 1/3 or 2/3 with probability 1/2 each. Similarly, $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{R(t)}{B(t)} = \frac m n$ is not correct, since $R(t),B(t)$ are random variables which don't have a number for a limit. It should say $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{R(t)}{B(t)}\right) = \frac m n$. Actually it is even $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{R(t)}{B(t)}\right) = \frac m n$.

There is another issue with your considerations: The equation for $x$ is actually true for any $x$, it simplifies to 0=0, so there is no reason to assume that $x=m+n$. In fact, if m and n are coprime, then the first opportunity for the ratio to become exactly $\frac m n$ again is precisely after $m+n$ steps, but the probability that it does is certainly not 1. Therefore the expectation is larger in this case. However if m=2n and n is very large, then there is about a 50% chance of returning to the same ratio after just 2 moves.

Thank you everyone for your time and efforts!

This is just a long comment, rather than a full answer.
Let $X=\min \left\{ t > 0 \colon \frac{R(t)}{B(t)} = \frac{m}{n} \right\}$. Also let's assume that $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Then $P(X=t)=0$ when $t$ is not divisible by $m+n$. Let's look at $P(X\le k(m+n))$.
Consider the event $S_t$ defined as $R(t(m+n))=(t+1)m$ and $B(t(m+n))=(t+1)n$ simultaneously. Then $P(X\le k(m+n))=P(S_1\cup \cdots\cup S_k)$.
We can use inclusion-exclusion for this, but we first need to find the "intersection probabilities". That is, we need to find $P\left(\cap_{i\in I} S_i\right)$, where $I\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$. If we order $I$, then this is $\prod_{r=1}^{|I|}P(S_{I_r}|S_{I_1},\ldots,S_{I_{r-1}})$. But because only the most recent state matters, this simplifies to $\prod_{r=1}^{|I|}P(S_{I_r}|S_{I_{r-1}})$
This actually isn't too hard to find given the probability given here because it's as if we are just recalculating the required probabilities with new parameters. If I didn't mess anything up (in terms of how many balls there are at the end of the relevant set, and how many are getting added), it comes out to $$\prod_{r=1}^{|I|}\binom{(m+n)(I_r-I_{r-1})}{m(I_r-I_{r-1})}\frac{(m(I_{r-1}+1))^{\overline{m(I_r-I_{r-1})}}(n(I_{r-1}+1))^{\overline{n(I_r-I_{r-1})}}}{((m+n)(I_{r-1}+1))^{\overline{(m+n)(I_r-I_{r-1})}}}$$ where $I_0$ is understood to be $0$. This simplifies kind of nicely to $$\frac{m^{\overline{mI_{|I|}}}n^{\overline{nI_{|I|}}}}{(m+n)^{\overline{(m+n)I_{|I|}}}}\prod_{r=1}^{|I|}\binom{(m+n)(I_r-I_{r-1})}{m(I_r-I_{r-1})}$$ Here, $I_{|I|}$ is just the largest value of $I$.
Of course, now we'd want to actually work with this in the inclusion-exclusion formula...

@ Varun: thank you for your answer! Can you please expand on the last part, i.e. the inclusion-exclusion formula?

@konofoso I was referring to this. In this context, the final probability of $\mathbb{P}(X\le k(m+n))$ would be $$\sum_{s=1}^k\left((-1)^{s-1}\sum_{\substack{I\subseteq{1,\ldots,k}\|I|=s}}\mathbb{P}(I)\right)$$, where $\mathbb{P}(I)$ is given by the formula in my answer.

The quantity $T:=\min\left\{ t>0 : \frac {R(t)}{B(t)} = \frac m n\right\}$ can have infinite expectation:
Polya's Urn model can be understood as a certain monotone random walk $X(t)=(R(t),B(t))$ on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ where the question is when do we hit the line through the origin again that we start on. In the simple case $m=n$, the line in question is the line $R=B$.
Let's focus on this case. We will define a strongly dependent random walk $Y$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ as follows: $Y$ starts at $0$. If $R=B$, $Y$ will increase by $1$ if and only if a red ball is added to the urn, otherwise it will decrease by $1$. If $R>B$, then the likelihood of adding a red ball is $\frac R {R+B}> \frac 1 2$, so we can define $Y$ to increase by $1$ with a probability of exactly $\frac 1 2$ but only if a red ball was added. Otherwise it decreases by $1$. Similarly if $R<B$, the likelihood of adding a blue ball is larger than $\frac 1 2$ so we can make it that $Y$ decreases by $1$ with probability $\frac 1 2$, but only if a blue ball was added. Otherwise it increases by $1$. Note that $Y$ is just a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ that either increases or decreases by $1$ with a probability of $\frac 1 2$ each. This random walk is well-understood. In particular, it is known that the walk is so-called recurrent null, that is, it will come back to its starting point with probability 1, but the expected time until it does is infinite.
Since both walks are symmetric in exchanging blue and red, we can assume the first ball is red and $Y$ starts out in the positive. Now we know the expected time $Y$ returns to $0$ is infinite, so we just have to argue, that $X$ hits the line $R=B$ later than that. For instance, it is sufficient to show that $Y\leq R-B$ until it returns to $0$. However this is just true by definition, because $Y$ can only ever increase by $1$ if $R-B$ does as well and else it decreases by $1$, which is the most decrease that can happen within a single step to $R-B$ as well.

The idea of modeling the problem as a random walk is a good one, but the details given here are incomplete or in some places misleading. I would happily upvote a revised answer with more precision.

@ F.U.A.S. : thank you for your answer!

@Greg Martin : thank you for your feedback! Do you think you can post an answer if you have time please?

@GregMartin could you point me to what is missing? When we are off the line, say $R>B$, then adding a red ball has probability $\frac R {R+B}>\frac 1 2$, so we can run a coupled random walk with probability $\frac 1 2$ that stays as close to the line as the other one, if not closer, but which returns to it only in expected infinite time.

It's getting better! I think you should say something about coupled random walks in the post itself, with details (or at least a link to a resource) for the many readers who are unfamiliar with them. I would also change “difference” to “ratio”.

@GregMartin Ok I edited it one last time, but since I want to compare it to the one-dimensional random walk, it does not work with the ratio, it only works with the difference.
